# Using Initialized Factory and Inheritence to create a custom object

Tags: c#, inheritance, nunit, factory

I am attempting to make a customized object using the factory pattern.  Ideally I want to have some base object that can be inherited from but the specifc object can act like the base object as well as do specific tasks only it can do.  I can't seem to access the base object's data though the newly created object.  I have looked at some tutorials and cobbled together what I think should work but hit a wall.

For now I am doing this by instansiationg a factory to make it easier to test later on.  I've tried to access FilterPanel directly by not making it abstract but I'm not sure that is good coding practice.

Why am I unable to access the FilterPanel functions?

***FilterPanel***

```
public abstract class FilterPanel {

    //Do generic stuff that all filters can do.
    public void ClickFilterButtons(){...}
}
```

***FilterFactory***

```
    public class FilterFactory {

    public FilterPanel CreateFilterPanel(string filterType) {

        FilterPanel filterPanel;
        switch (filterType) {

            case "invoice":
                filterPanel = new InvoiceFilter();
                break;

            case "payment":
                filterPanel = new PaymentFilter();
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception("wrong filter!");
                break;
        }
        return filterPanel;
    }
}

public class InvoiceFilter : FilterPanel {

    //Do specific stuff only Invoice filter can do.
    public void InvoiceStuff(){...}
}

public class PaymentFilter : FilterPanel {

    //Do specific stuff only payment filter can do.
    public void PaymentStuff(){...}
}
```

***TestFile***

```
        [Test]
        FilterFactory filter = new FilterFactory();
        filter.CreateFilterPanel("invoice");

        //Cannot access this function in the base filter class functions.
        filter.ClickFilterButtons();
```

Comment: make sure they are public; in your code example check the line `FilterFactory filter` (`var filter = filterFactory.Create()` ?)

Comment: The issue is I cannot call the member of the factory at all.  No functions appear for it from the test file's view.  That is preventing me from producing any complete or verifiable code.  The filter object in the TestFile portion does not allow me access to the base object.  "//Cannot access this function in the base filter class functions."

Comment: I have corrected that.  And no it won't compile because I cannot access the FilterPanel piece from createing a factory and using an Invoice or Payment class who inherits from FilterPanel.  That is the issue.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  I am under the assumption because FilterPanel is defined as abstract I need to use it from the factory instead.  I was using the factory to avoid instansiating a FilterPanel directly, rather just using an Invoice or Payment object instead.  I have corrected the access modifier, it is indeed public.

Comment: you are using the factory object to access the FilterPanel which will not work, try using the created object returned from the CreateFilterPanel

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to call the member on the wrong object.

```
//Create the factory
FilterFactory factory = new FilterFactory();
//Create the filter using the factory
FilterPanel filter = factory.CreateFilterPanel("invoice");
//Call the public member on the returned filter
filter.ClickFilterButtons();
//To access InvoiceFilter specific stuff you need to cast
if(filter is InvoiceFilter) {
    (filter as InvoiceFilter).InvoiceStuff();
}
```